# Average of function

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have function:

$$\sin^4\left(\frac{r\pi}{R}\right)\frac{r}{R}$$

where $R$ is a constant and $r$ has a maximum value $r_{max}=R$. I want to average the function over area $\pi R^2$. How can I do this ?

The function $f(r)$ is a radial function and $x^2+y^2<R$.

Comment: Does your function $f(r)$ come from a *radial function* $f(x,y)$ defined in the disc $x^2+y^2\leq R^2$?

Comment: Yes, function f(r) is a radial function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your function $f(r):=\sin^4 (\pi r/R)\ (r/R)$ is the radial expression of the radial function of two real variables $f(x,y):= \sin^4 (\pi \sqrt{x^2+y^2}/R)\ (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}/R)$ defined in the disc $D:=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\ x^2+y^2\leq R^2\}$, because otherwise it will have no meaning to average $f(r)$ over an area.

The average of such an $f(x,y)$ over $D$ is then given by:
$$\overline{f} := \frac{1}{\operatorname{area}(D)}\ \iint_D f(x,y)\ \text{d}x\text{d}y\; ;$$
the integral in the RH side can be computed using polar coordinates, hence:
$$\begin{split}
\overline{f} &:= \frac{1}{\pi R^2}\ \int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} f(r)\ r\ \text{d}r\text{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{2}{R^2}\ \int_0^R f(r)\ r\ \text{d}r\\
&= \frac{2}{R^2}\ \int_0^R \sin^4 \left(\pi \frac{r}{R}\right)\ \frac{r^2}{R}\ \text{d}r\\
&\stackrel{t=\pi r/R}{=} \frac{2}{\pi R^2}\ \int_0^\pi t^2\ \sin^4 t\ \text{d}t\; .
\end{split}$$
The latter integral can be computed using standard integration by parts techniques, which (after lenghty and tedious computations) yield:
$$\begin{split}
\int_0^\pi t^2\ \sin^4 t\ \text{d}t &= \frac{1}{256} \left( 32 t^3+ 32(2t^2-1)\sin 2t +(8t^2-1)\sin 4t -64t\cos 2t +4t\cos 4t\right)\Bigg|_0^{\pi}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{64}\ (8\pi^2-15)\; ,
\end{split}$$
therefore:
$$\overline{f} = \frac{8\pi^2-15}{32R^2}\; .$$

Comment: This is a great answer. It helps a lot. I was looking for an average by taking square of the function and multiplying by $2*\pi r$. Which was not clear to me.